# OpenCV accumulatedWeight error (assertion fails on comparison of channels and size)

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, g++

I am running the following code to calculated the Running Average of a collection of images read from a video on OpenCV.

**EDIT:** (Code updated)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdio>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/video/video.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc < 2) {
        printf("Quitting. Insufficient parameters\n");
        return 0;
    }
    char c;
    int frameNum = -1;

    const char* WIN_MAIN = "Main Window";
    namedWindow(WIN_MAIN, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    VideoCapture capture;
    capture.open(argv[1]);
    Mat acc, img;
    capture.retrieve(img, 3);
    acc = Mat::zeros(img.size(), CV_32FC3);
    for(;;) {
        if(!capture.grab()) {
            printf("End of frame\n");
            break;
        }

        capture.retrieve(img, 3);
        Mat floating;
        img.convertTo(floating, CV_32FC3);
        accumulateWeighted(floating, acc, 0.01);
        imshow(WIN_MAIN, img);
        waitKey(10);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

On running the code with a sample video the following error pops up

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dst.size == src.size && dst.channels() == cn) in accumulateWeighted, file /usr/lib/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/accum.cpp, line 430
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /usr/lib/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/accum.cpp:430: error: (-215) dst.size == src.size && dst.channels() == cn in function accumulateWeighted

Aborted (core dumped)
```

What could be the possible reason for the error? Could you please guide me in the right direction?

Compiler used : g++
OpenCV version : 2.4.5

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the refman:

```
src – Input image as 1- or 3-channel, 8-bit or 32-bit ﬂoating point.
dst – Accumulator image with the same number of channels as input image, 32-bit or 64-bit
ﬂoating-point.
```

so, your camera input img CV_8UC3, and your acc img is (currently) CV_32F. that's a misfit.

you want 3channel floating point for acc, so that's :

```
acc = Mat::zeros(img.size(), CV_8UC3);`
```

for more precision, you want to change your img to float type, too, so it would be:

```
   acc = Mat::zeros(img.size(), CV_32FC3);  // note: 3channel now

    for (;;) {

        if(!capture.grab()) {
            printf("End of frame\n");
            break;
        }

        capture.retrieve(img); // video probably has 1 stream only
        Mat floatimg;
        img.convertTo(floatimg, CV_32FC3);
        accumulateWeighted(floatimg, acc, 0.01);
```

EDIT:

try to replace your grab/retrieve sequence by:

```
for(;;) {
    capture >> img;
    if ( img.empty() )
        break;
```

Comment: I updated the code. It still doesn't seem to work. Gives the same error.

Comment: capture.retrieve(img, 3);    <- looks highly suspicious. i bet you don't have 4 streams there ( this would access the 4th ).

Comment: Changed it to 2, still doesn't work. Will try the change that you have mentioned in the edit.

Comment: you probably don't have more than 1 stream there. the stream id is for cameras with multiple heads ( think kinect ). it's not an rgb channel! ( and 3 [aka the 4th] would hav been wrong anyway )

Comment: Replaced the grab/retrieve sequence with the stream operator and empty check. It's weird that it's giving the same error. If I comment out the accumulatedWeight function everything works fine and I can see the video in a window as it's supposed to. I am using an flv for testing it out. Can that be a problem? I am sorry, I am really new to image processing and OpenCV both.

Answer (score 0):

As I can read in the OpenCV documentation of [retrieve](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=retrieve#bool%20VideoCapture%3a%3aretrieve%28Mat&%20image,%20int%20channel%29)

> C++: bool VideoCapture::retrieve(Mat& image, int channel=0);

second argument is the channel
and in the documentation of [accumulateWeighted](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#accumulateweighted) it says :

> C++: void accumulateWeighted(InputArray src, InputOutputArray dst,
>   double alpha, InputArray mask=noArray() )
>
> Parameters:src – Input image as 1- or 3-channel, 8-bit or 32-bit
>   floating point.

But in your code :

```
capture.retrieve(img, 2);
```

I guess you have the wrong channel parameter

Comment: Anyway, you're problem seems to be caused by channels of both img. Because Dst is constructed with src's size so the failure of the assert may be  from `dst.channels() == cn` with `cn = src.channels()`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem problem and here's my solution.

```
Mat frame, acc;
// little hack, read the first frame
capture >> frame;
acc = Mat::zeros(frame.size(), CV_32FC3);

for(;;) {
...
```